# How to colour wordpress menu lis based on category assigned to each page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, categories

I would like to create a nav menu that displays all the pages of a wordpress site, its layout similar to what you would see in a footer sitemap layout, approx 5 columns with all the pages shown. Each page will be a project. I want to use wordpress category checkboxes (like you have for posts) to allow selection of one relevant category for each project page. Each page will then show a category caption below the project's description text, this I will style with CSS so each category has a different background colour.

Because Wordpress doesn't provide categories for pages, I have found a plugin to add this category feature to pages called ninja-page-categories-and-tags: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ninja-page-categories-and-tags/

It's possible to edit the plugin php code under basic-functions.php to return a 'class' for the category displayed using get_slug and then applying css for each.

My problem is that on the menu, which will be a secondary menu in Thirty Ten displaying the pages, I want to be able to colour the background of each link to match the category that has previously been assigned to each page using the ninja plugin. Because the menu works with pages and the categories are not directly linked to the menu items (firebug will not show category details in the html of each link to reference with the css) I am wondering how I can colour each link based on category? Any ideas?

Ultimately what I would like to achieve is a grid of page links that are all coloured based on their category, a colour coded menu.

The plugin uses the standard wordpress category functionality but I just can't think how to connect these category details to the menu items to allow me to style them with css, any help would be really appreciated, even if just a point in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a demo site, or can you put the relevant code in a [JSfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) - it would make it MUCH easier to help you..

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. There are so many php files includes etc in Wordpress that I don't know what I'd need to post or JSfiddle to you. I could post the php code from the plugin but even that has about 5 php files? Essentially to demo this its the same as having a new wordpress site and adding items to the wordpress menu, then install the ninja categories plugin, edit the pages (as shown in the menu) select category for each. Then just need to find out away to colour the menu items based on the categories applied to each page. cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're after, but essentially if you want to add extra classes to menu items (which will allow styling), you need to create a custom walker function.

Have a look at a tutorial like this: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/